# Model for time series analysis

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, pca, forecast, data-analysis

I'm new to data analysis and ML in general. I'm working with some friends on this problem: We're trying to predict when a component of a machine will stop working properly so the client can change it in time to avoid production slowdowns. We have a dataset in which are registered:

- Timestamp
- Event description
- Event type id
- Machine id
- List item

There are 2 types of events, each one with an id:

- ID: 0 -> completed piece event, all ok (**Event description**: E_INFO_PIECE_COMPLETATED)
- ID: 1 -> error event that indicates something went wrong

There are a lot of events with the error type, which are described by the **Event description** column, for example, E_ALARM_CUTTING_DRIVE_ERROR or E_ALARM_LOW_AIR_PRESSURE.

We tried to understand if there is a correlation between all these error events and if they repeat over time by following a specific pattern but ended with very poor results.

Some arguments we discussed are:

- ARIMA
- PCA
- Time series anomaly detection

But we don't know if these models can be applied to our case or, if yes, how.
So the question is:

- Is there a model that we can adopt using the current data (Event description and timestamp)? If not, do we need more data, like sensor values?

Comment: The paper "Machine learning application for sensor failure detection in polymerization process" in [SBrT 2018](https://www.dropbox.com/s/89k2t7swo064afk/Anais_SBrT_2018_v2.pdf?dl=0) might give you some ideas